# Permission for selecting a Best Answer for a Question in Chatter

Tags: community, experience-cloud

I was reading one salesforce document on how to make an answer as best answer. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_chatter_questions_best_answer.htm&type=5

If a user doesn’t have permission to select the best answer for a question, they don’t see the Select as Best option, but it doesn't say what kind of permission is required to mark it as best answer.

I am trying give access with which someone can mark the best answer without accessing the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have 'Create and Set Up Experiences' permission on profile or on permission set to select as best answer for a question.  However user who doesn't have above permission will be able to see once it is marked as Best Answer by Admin/moderator.

Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_chatter_company_verify.htm&type=5).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give any User access to mark best answer, there is system permission called as "Moderate Chatter Feeds in Experience Cloud sites". This permission exists at profile level inside system permissions. Be aware as this will grant additional permissions as well like delete other's post/questions permissions.